# How resolve a warning in IAR 'Reset_Handler'

Tags: iar

I'm using IAR ARM 7.10 and getting a warning:

> Warning[25]: Label 'Reset_Handler' is defined pubweak in a section implicitly declared root...

It is cause the system reset sometimes.

How do I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, straight from [iAR Support page](http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=30605&from=search%20result):

Problem

After upgrading to EWARM 7.10.1 the Warning[25] is issued during assembly of a file that assembled without warning on earlier version of EWARM.

Background

The assembler (iasmarm) is (from EWARM 7.10.1) issuing Warning[25] for a deprecated assembler construction.

The deprecated assembler source construction looks like this:

```
  PUBWEAK NMI_Handler
  SECTION .text:CODE:REORDER(1)
```

NMI_Handler
Solution

To avoid the warning, add ":NOROOT" to the "SECTION" statement:

```
  PUBWEAK NMI_Handler
  SECTION .text:CODE:REORDER:NOROOT(1)
```

NMI_Handler

Answer (score 2):

In "startup_*.s" file replace string

```
SECTION .text:CODE:REORDER(1)
```

with string

```
SECTION .text:CODE:NOROOT:REORDER(1)
```

just before every symbol wich cause the warning.

Comment: This warning only started being shown after upgrading to version 7.10. Any idea what changed in the assembler to cause this? Why was it ok before, because every ARM vendor example I've seen gets this warning now.

Comment: Before 7.10 sections were noroot by defaut, but now default value is root. I don't know why the have done this. It forces linker to include sections into executive even if no symbols used from this section.